# Using Jest, how do I mock a method of a module used in a component to see how many times it's been called and with what values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to mock a component which imports a history module to change the url. I just want to be able to mock the `history.push` method and check that it's been called and with what arguments after I've performed some user actions on it.

```
// MyForm
import { Component } from 'react'
import history from 'main/lib/history'

class MyForm extends Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const res = await fetch('BAD_URL')
      // do some stuff

    } catch (e) {
      history.push('error_page')
    }
  }

  render() {
    // ...
  }
}

export default MyForm
```

```
// Testing MyForm
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import MyForm from 'src/MyForm'

const mockPush = jest.fn((url) => {
  console.log('history pushing to this url:', url)
})

jest.mock('main/lib/history', () => {
  return jest.fn(() => {
    return {
      push: mockPush
    }
  })
})

test('history is pushed', () => {
  render(
    <MyForm />
  )
  expect(mockPush).toHaveBeenCalled() // 0 calls
})
```

It seems like any variations in implementation of this test I've tried either only show the console log and don't record the calls or cause errors.

Comment: Use [spyOn](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname)

Comment: how do you see what arguments have been passed with spyOn?

Comment: no worries worked it out, will answer my own question

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, used spyOn and checked the spy.mock.calls to check the arguments passed.

```
// Testing MyForm
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import MyForm from 'src/MyForm'
import history from 'main/lib/history'

jest.mock('main/lib/history', () => ({
  push: (url) => {
    console.log('history.push:', url)
  }
}))

test('history is pushed', () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(history, 'push')

  render(
    <MyForm />
  )

  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled() // true ... 1 call
  expect(spy.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe('error_page') // true
})
```

Not sure if there's a better way but this worked for me.